# lme4: "number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations"

Tags: r, lme4

I am fitting a model using lme4, but I get an error.
Here is

```r
flower_data <- data.frame(
    id = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'K', 'K'),
    flower = c(1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 7, 2, 7, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 9, 4, 9, 5, 10, 5, 10),
    score = c(80, 80, 75, 70, 90, 80, 85, 80, 70, 79, 88, 90, 77, 100, 92, 90, 83, 100, 71, 100)
```

In these data, `id` are nested in flower; I want to get   variances for `id`, `flower` and `id:flower`.

```r
model <- lmer(score ~  (1|id/flower), data = flower_data)
```

I get an error when I use this model:

> number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `lmer` models always include a residual variance term. (2) Your data only has a single observation per `flower`/`id` combination, so the "`flower` nested within `id`" variance is identical to/confounded with the residual variance. (3) If you don't try to include that term explicitly, the "Residual" term will be exactly the `id:flower` variance.

```r
model <- lmer(score ~  (1|id) + (1|flower), data = flower_data)
print(VarCorr(model), comp = "Variance")
 Groups   Name        Variance
 id       (Intercept)  7.0468 
 flower   (Intercept) 42.2073 
 Residual             45.4269
```

If you insist, you can override the warnings and force `lmer` to fit this model:

```r
model2 <- update(model, . ~ . + (1|id:flower), 
    control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore", 
                          check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore"))
## warnings ("degenerate Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalue")
 Groups    Name        Variance
 id:flower (Intercept) 23.0890 
 flower    (Intercept) 42.2084 
 id        (Intercept)  7.0468 
 Residual              22.3373
```

Now the sum of the `Residual` and `id:flower` variances is the same as the previous `Residual` variance. The division is arbitrary; any two non-negative values that added up to the original Residual variance would be equally good fits to the data ...